# Switch Case statement enum not working?

Tags: java, enums

I have a problem concerning switch/case statements in java in combination with enums.

In my code I want to do something based on the Enum of the type "MatchingMethods" set in the object "currentMethod".
The enum "MatchingMethods" contains several enums in the form

```
{EXACT_STRING_MATCHING, DEPTH_MATCHING, [...]}
```

Now the strange thing is though the object "currentMethod" contains an enum of the type "EXACT_STRING_MATCHING" not only the first case is executed but also the second one.

I know there is no break statement after the code of the first case but the code of the second case shouldn't be executed in my opinion because the enum "EXACT_STRING_MATCHING" doesn'T match with "DEPTH_MATCHING".

If I put in a break statement after the first case it seem to be totally fine…

My code is the following:

```
    [...]
    MatchingMethods mM = currentMethod.getMatchMethod();

    switch (currentMethod.getMatchMethod()) {
    case EXACT_STRING_MATCHING:
        //do something here
    case DEPTH_MATCHING:
        comparedNodePair.setDepthMatchResult(currentMetricResult);
        break;
    [...]
```

I am totally confused…

May someone be able to help me?

Comment: You seem to be missing a break in your first case, unless that's from you removing code.

Comment: See the [doc of switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: This is nothing to do with enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already mentioned it, you have no `break` - `switch` works like `goto` where the `case` are labels to be jumped at and no "boundaries" or functions.

This is also the biggest critique concerning `switch`, because no one would use `goto` today, but `switch` which is certainly similar.

Comment: But the code from the second case shouldn't be executed, right?

I thought if there is no break after one case that matches, all following cases are evaluated as well IF THEY match. Or I am not right?

Comment: Yes, it should be executed, because `case` are *not* evaluations but rather labels.

Answer (score 2):

But it gets executed, because once one of the case satements is true the flow of execution "falls trough" see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for some information

Answer (score 0):

this is normal if there is no break statement at the end of the case block.
add the break statement is necessary if you only want the exact block to be executed.